# Query and parse xml attribute value into XLS using VBA

Tags: xml, excel, parsing, vba

I'm trying to open/load an XML file specified in an Excel worksheet in the range `B2`. Then, search through a list of XML attributes for `name=FUNCTIONAL_ITEM` and get all the attribute values after `">`.

In the following example, i'd like to extract out the value `8`, `9` and `10`.

```
<Attribute name="BIN" dataType="String" unit="" multiplier="" tag="LINE,MRPM">1</Attribute>
<Attribute name="FUNCTIONAL_ITEM" dataType="Double" unit="" multiplier="" tag="LINE,LINE DB">8</Attribute>
<Attribute name="FUNCTIONAL_ITEM" dataType="Double" unit="" multiplier="" tag="LINE,LINE DB">9</Attribute>
<Attribute name="FUNCTIONAL_ITEM" dataType="Double" unit="" multiplier="" tag="LINE,LINE DB">10</Attribute>
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction for implementing this.

Comment: Sorry, this question is way to broad. Break it down it to steps and research them independently. 1. Retrieving file name from range. 2. Opening an Xml file. 3. Parsing Xml from VBA. I'm guessing you can find answers for all of those *already* here on Stack Overflow. If not, ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is XPath. Assuming that you have your XML document in a `DomDocument60` object which we'll call `d` and you have declared an `IXMLDOMNodeList` variable called `i` then use this:

`Set i = d.selectNodes("//Attribute[@name='FUNCTIONAL ITEM']")`

You can then iterate through the nodes in `i`and extract the `text` property from each node.

Here's a fairly minimal program to demonstrate (you need to add a reference to "Microsoft XML, v6.0" via Tools > References if you haven't done so already):

```
Sub main()

Dim d As DOMDocument60
Dim i As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode

Set d = New DOMDocument60
d.Load 'file path goes here

Debug.Print "*****"
Set i = d.selectNodes("//Attribute[@name='FUNCTIONAL ITEM']")
For Each n In i
    Debug.Print n.Text
Next n
Debug.Print "*****"

End Sub
```